# VBScript: What is the simplest way to format a string?

Tags: vbscript, formatting, string-formatting

I have the following format:
Value1 is {0} and Value2 is {1}.

I need to replace the numbers in the brackets with strings.  This is easily done in most languages using string.Format or something along those lines.  How can I do this using only vbscript?

I've tried:

```
Replace (strFormat, "{0}", value1)  
Replace (strFormat, "{1}", value2)
```

It does not work.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `Replace (strFormat, "{0}", value1)`

Based on your code snip, I'm guessing you believe Replace mutates `strFormat` directly.  It doesn't work like that; You assign the result to the original variable like this:

```
strFormat = Replace (strFormat, "{0}", value1)
```

You can also assign to *another* variable to store the changed results, like this:

```
strFormat2 = Replace (strFormat, "{0}", value1)
```

Comment: Hehe, Thanks.  It's always something simple.

Comment: he doesnt need _another_ variable, but just to update original string.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted something similar and didn't like any of these answers as they meant multiple lines for each value (Ignoring Beaner's answer is for the wrong language!) so I created the following:

```
Public Function StrFormat(FormatString, Arguments())
    Dim Value, CurArgNum

    StrFormat = FormatString

    CurArgNum = 0
    For Each Value In Arguments
        StrFormat = Replace(StrFormat, "{" & CurArgNum & "}", Value)
        CurArgNum = CurArgNum + 1
    Next
End Function
```

You can use the following then *(note that you need to add "Array()" around your variables)*:

```
formatString = "Test '{0}', '{2}', '{1}' and {0} again!"
Response.Write StrFormat(formatString, Array(1, 2, "three", "Unused"))
Response.Write StrFormat(formatString, Array(4, 5, "six", "Unused"))
```

Which will output what you expect:

```
Test '1', 'three', '2' and 1 again!
Test '4', 'six', '5' and 4 again!
```

Hope this feels a bit more natural for people from other languages.

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer; simple and reusable. I almost upvoted it, but then I ran into trouble. Thing is, your example modifies `SourceString`. That's no good when `SourceString` contains a format string that you will be reusing. Subsequent calls to `StringFormat(SourceString, ...)` won't work because `SourceString` contains the result of the previous call. I'll edit your answer to fix this.

Comment: Edited. I changed the name of the parameter `SourceString` to `FormatString`. Eg. [.Net's String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) has the name `format` for the first parameter. Now, I can upvote!

Comment: The only possible problem I see with this solution is that arguments that contain later argument number formats will be replaced themselves.

Answer (score 4):

As **none** of the answers so far addresses the problem of **formatting** (as opposed
to interpolating/splicing strings into strings):

This simple Class:

```
Class cFormat
  Private m_oSB
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
  End Sub ' Class_Initialize
  Public Function formatOne(sFmt, vElm)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat sFmt, vElm
    formatOne = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatOne
  Public Function formatArray(sFmt, aElms)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aElms)
    formatArray = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatArray
End Class ' cFormat
```

harness .NET formatting for VBScript via COM. Now you can do:

```
-------- Interpolation
Use    |Value1 is {0} and Value2 is {1}.|
to get |Value1 is zero and Value2 is one.|
from   |zero one|

Use    |{0} x 2 => {0}{0}|
to get |once x 2 => onceonce|
from   |once|

-------- Cherrypicking
Use    |{6,4}: [{0}, {2}, {4}]|
to get |even: [0, 2, 4]|
from   |0 1 2 3 4 5 even odd|

Use    |{7,4}: [{5}, {3}, {1}]|
to get | odd: [5, 3, 1]|
from   |0 1 2 3 4 5 even odd|

-------- Conversions
Use    ||{0:D}| |{0:X}| |{0:N3}| |{0:P2}| (german locale!)|
to get ||123| |7B| |123,000| |12.300,00%| (german locale!)|
from   |123|

Use    ||{0}| |{0:U}| |{0:u}||
to get ||29.06.2012 14:50:30| |Freitag, 29. Juni 2012 12:50:30| |2012-06-29 14:50:30Z||
from   |29.06.2012 14:50:30|

Use    ||{0}| |{0:E1}| |{0:N1}| |{0:N2}| |{0:N3}||
to get ||1234,56| |1,2E+003| |1.234,6| |1.234,56| |1.234,560||
from   |1234,56|

-------- Alignment
Use    ||{0,1:D}| |{0,2:D}| |{0,-2:D}| |{0,5:D}| |{0,-5:D}||
to get ||12| |12| |12| |   12| |12   ||
from   |12|
```

If you are interested in the test/demo script to do some experiments
of your own:

```
Option Explicit

' Class cFormat ...

Dim oFormat : Set oFormat = New cFormat
Dim aTests  : aTests      = Array( _
    Array("Interpolation" _
      , Array( _
            Array(True,  "Value1 is {0} and Value2 is {1}.", Array("zero", "one")) _
          , Array(False, "{0} x 2 => {0}{0}"               , "once"              ) _
        } _
    ) _
  , Array("Cherrypicking" _
      , Array( _
            Array(True , "{6,4}: [{0}, {2}, {4}]", Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "even", "odd")) _
          , Array(True , "{7,4}: [{5}, {3}, {1}]", Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "even", "odd")) _
        } _
    ) _
  , Array("Conversions" _
      , Array( _
            Array(False, "|{0:D}| |{0:X}| |{0:N3}| |{0:P2}| (german locale!)", 123      ) _
          , Array(False, "|{0}| |{0:U}| |{0:u}|"                             , Now     ) _
          , Array(False, "|{0}| |{0:E1}| |{0:N1}| |{0:N2}| |{0:N3}|"         , 1234.56 ) _
        } _
    ) _
  , Array("Alignment" _
      , Array( _
            Array(False, "|{0,1:D}| |{0,2:D}| |{0,-2:D}| |{0,5:D}| |{0,-5:D}|", 12 ) _
        } _
    ) _
)
Dim sFormat : sFormat = "Use    |{0}|{3}to get |{1}|{3}from   |{2}|{3}"
Dim aData   : aData   = Array(0, 1, 2, vbCrLf)
Dim aTest
For Each aTest In aTests
    WScript.Echo "--------", aTest(0)
    Dim aSample
    For Each aSample In aTest(1)
        aData(0) = aSample(1)
        If aSample(0) Then
           aData(1) = oFormat.formatArray(aSample(1), aSample(2))
           aData(2) = Join(aSample(2))
        Else
           aData(1) = oFormat.formatOne(  aSample(1), aSample(2))
           aData(2) = aSample(2)
        End If
        WScript.Echo oFormat.formatArray(sFormat, aData)
    Next
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

To learn about formatting in .NET, start with [StringBuilder.AppendFormat Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b.aspx) and [Formatting Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616669/603855) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615874/603855) for ideas to include (not Copy&Paste) such a Class into your script.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice little function that works something like the .NET string.Format function. I did this quickly so adding err handling is up to you. I did this in VB6 and added a reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5**

```
Public Function StringFormat(ByVal SourceString As String, ParamArray Arguments() As Variant) As String
   Dim objRegEx As RegExp  ' regular expression object
   Dim objMatch As Match   ' regular expression match object
   Dim strReturn As String ' the string that will be returned

   Set objRegEx = New RegExp
   objRegEx.Global = True
   objRegEx.Pattern = "(\{)(\d)(\})"

   strReturn = SourceString
   For Each objMatch In objRegEx.Execute(SourceString)
      strReturn = Replace(strReturn, objMatch.Value, Arguments(CInt(objMatch.SubMatches(1))))
   Next objMatch

   StringFormat = strReturn

End Function
```

*Example:*

StringFormat("Hello {0}. I'd like you to meet {1}. They both work for {2}. {0} has worked for {2} for 15 years.", "Bruce", "Chris", "Kyle")

Returns:

Hello Bruce. I'd like you to meet Chris. They both work for Kyle. Bruce has worked for Kyle for 15 years.

Comment: A few adjustments might be made for VBScript, but this function looks like it might be versatile than just a simple Replace function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? This code works here:

```
value1 = "1"
value2 = "2"

strFormat = "Value1 is {0} and Value2 is {1}."
strFormat = Replace (strFormat, "{0}", value1)  
strFormat = Replace (strFormat, "{1}", value2)

MsgBox strFormat
```

Note I update my `strFormat` value for every replace.

If you needs a more flexible implementation, you can go with a regular expression, but doesn't seems required now.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the functionality of @Ekkehard.Horner's StringBuilder-based solution, but it seemed more complicated than necessary.

For my purposes, I definitely do not need the ceremony of a whole class.

I pared it down to this single function:

```vb
Function FormatString(format, args)
    dim resultBuilder

    set resultBuilder = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
    
    if IsArray(args) Then
        resultBuilder.AppendFormat_4 format, (args)
    else
        resultBuilder.AppendFormat format, args
    end if

    FormatString = resultBuilder.ToString()
End Function

WScript.Echo FormatString("Hello, {0}!", "World")
WScript.Echo FormatString("Hello, {0}! It is {1:H:mm tt}, and we are {2:P2} through the day on {1:dddd, d MMMM, yyyy}.", Array("World", Now, Timer/(24*60*60)))
```