# DateAdd() in Special Format

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I've tried all the ways I see to add a month to a certain date then return that in a specific format but I'm at a loss.  Here's my code but I need to format it:

```vb
replace( formatdatetime( dateadd( "m" , 1 , request("date") ), 0 ) , "/" , "-" ) & "' )
```

`request("date")` is in `yyyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss` format and that's how I need the new date.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work perfect:

```
replace( formatdatetime( dateadd( "m" , 1 , cDate(request("date")) ), 0 ) , "/" , "-" )
```

Notice the use of the `cDate` function to convert a value to a date explicitly.

Edit:

I removed last part of your code `& "' )`, it gave me an error otherwise.

Comment: I accidentally included part of the SQL I was making this a part of; that's what the `& "'  )` is about.

Answer (score 1):

When working with dates, it's especially important to take care of the proper data (sub)types. Feeding a string to a function that expects a date (and relying on 'VBScript - and your local settings - will do the right thing') is dangerous.

Using replace will never change the order of the date parts.

FormatDateTime depends on the local/regional settings and should be avoided as a sure path to disaster.

One way to solve this problem + most of all other problems concerning fancy formatting in VBScript is to use a .Net **System.Text.StringBuilder**:

Given Lib.vbs:

```
' Lib.vbs - simple VBScript library/module
' use
'  ExecuteGlobal goFS.OpenTextFile(<PathTo\Lib.vbs>).ReadAll()
' to 'include' Lib.vbs in you main script

Class ToBeAShamedOf
  Public a
  Public b
End Class ' ToBeAShamedOf

Class cFormat
  Private m_oSB
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
  End Sub ' Class_Initialize
  Public Function formatOne(sFmt, vElm)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat sFmt, vElm
    formatOne = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatOne
  Public Function formatArray(sFmt, aElms)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aElms)
    formatArray = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatArray
End Class ' cFormat
```

and main.vbs:

```
' main.vbs - demo use of library/module Lib.vbs

' Globals
Dim gsLibDir : gsLibDir = ".\"
Dim goFS     : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' LibraryInclude
ExecuteGlobal goFS.OpenTextFile(goFS.BuildPath(gsLibDir, "Lib.vbs")).ReadAll()

WScript.Quit demoDateFormat()
WScript.Quit main()

Function main()
  Dim o : Set o = New ToBeAShamedOf
  o.a = 4711
  o.b = "whatever"
  WScript.Echo o.a, o.b
  main = 1 ' can't call this a success
End Function ' main

Function demoDateFormat()
  Dim sD   : sD       = "2012-05-16 01:02:03" ' near future; not yyyyy!
  Dim dtD  : dtD      = CDate(sD)
  Dim dtDM : dtDM     = DateAdd("m", 1, dtD)
  Dim oFmt : Set oFmt = New cFormat
  WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray( _
      "   sD: {1}{0}  dtD: {2}{0} dtDM: {3}{0}dtDM': {4}" _
    , Array(vbCrLf, sD, dtD, dtDM, oFmt.formatOne("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}", dtDM)))
  demoDateFormat = 0 ' seems to be decent
End Function ' demoDateFormat
```

you'll get:

```
cscript main.vbs
   sD: 2012-05-16 01:02:03
  dtD: 16.05.2012 01:02:03
 dtDM: 16.06.2012 01:02:03
dtDM': 2012-06-16 01:02:03
```

(to be seen in the context of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615874/603855))

Comment: This is ASP Classic, not just VBScript. `WScript` is not available and `CreateObject` needs the `Server` prefix.

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
FormatDateTime(DateAdd("M",1,DateSerial(Left(request("date"),4),Mid(request("date"),9,2),Mid(request("date"),6,2))) & " " & Mid(request("date"),12,8),d,0)
```

It basically converts the string to a valid date in the native format, adds the 1 requested month and then rebuilds the string.

NOTE: request("date") looks as though it returns the current datetime so running it in this way may generate a final value that is a second or so out, if that's a problem then you will be better storing a static value in a variable, otherwise this should hopefully be ok.

Comment: Where does this Format(Value,FormatString) function come from?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I'm confused, are you saying this is not recognised as a vbs command. Format is available as part of VBA/VB6 and thus should be equally available in VBS?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Yep, my mistake, most are avail but this one is replaced with FormatDateTime, I've amended my post, cheers ^_^