# Sort an array of IPs in VB script

Tags: sorting, vbscript, ip-address

I'm looking to sort a list of IP addresses using VB script. I've looked for solutions in plenty of places so if this happens to be a duplicate, I welcome this being marked as one. I'm new to using VBS but the syntax is easy to understand so any working solution or guideline will do.
It seems tricky enough to accomplish due to VB not having a committed sort function (or Sub), as well as IPs being easy to misinterpret. I havn't tried anything as such yet.

Example:

```
123.123.123.123,
12.12.1.12,
23.34.56.11,
45.33.22.1,
1.3.5.55,
```

to become

```
1.3.5.55,
12.12.1.12,
23.34.56.11,
45.33.22.1,
123.123.123.123
```

Comment: Thanks for that. As a novice I thought they might be, due to the similar names and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the test data to

```
Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
  "123.123.123.123" _
, "12.12.1.12" _
, "23.34.56.11" _
, "45.33.22.1" _
, "1.3.5.55" _
)
```

and taking care of four elements in the format:

```
alVers.Add oFmt.formatArray("{0,4}.{1,4}.{2,4}.{3,4}", aParts)
```

the technique/code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660029/603855) produced the output:

```
123.123.123.123
12.12.1.12
23.34.56.11
45.33.22.1
1.3.5.55
---------------
   1.   3.   5.  55
  12.  12.   1.  12
  23.  34.  56.  11
  45.  33.  22.   1
 123. 123. 123. 123
---------------
1.3.5.55
12.12.1.12
23.34.56.11
45.33.22.1
123.123.123.123
```

Comment: Thanks but I only have the use of script, guess i'll have to do without.

Comment: @Sheepy99 - this **is** a script.

Comment: I get an error saying class not defined : new cFormat.
I assume you need to be use VB