# Convert Latitude/Longitude to decimal degrees

Tags: vbscript, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

i need to convert a large txt file with latitudes, and a large txt file with longitudes into decimal degrees.

The data i have is in the current format:

```
7d44'31.495"W for longitude
```

and

```
41d3'40.313"N for latitude
```

i need to convert both of this files to decimal degrees (using a script preferably). How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing nothing about *itudes, I can only give you a general idea about how
to solve your problem:

**Use a RegExp to cut the numbers from your data and feed them in a trusted formula**

To give you some confidence in my proposal, I show you, how I would tackle
the two sub-problems of your task.

**(1) Apply a RegExp on an input string and calculate.**

Based on this section

> Conversion from DMS to Decimal Degree
>
> Given a DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds) coordinate such as W87°43'41",
>   convert it to a number of decimal degrees using the following method:
>
> ```
> Calculate the total number of seconds:
> 43'41" = (43*60 + 41) = 2621 seconds.
> The fractional part is total number of seconds divided by 3600:
> 2621 / 3600 = ~0.728056
> Add fractional degrees to whole degrees to produce the final result:
> 87 + 0.728056 = 87.728056
> Since it is a West longitude coordinate, negate the result.
> The final result is -87.728056.
> ```

found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)

Code:

```
  Dim oFmt   : Set oFmt = New cFormat
  Dim oRE    : Set oRE  = New RegExp
  '                 0    1     2     3
  oRE.Pattern = "^([W])(\d+)°(\d+)'(\d+)""$"
  Dim aTests : aTests   = Array( _
      Array("W87°43'41""", -87.728056) _
  )
  Dim aTest
  For Each aTest In aTests
      Dim sInp : sInp     = aTest(0)
      Dim nExp : nExp     = aTest(1)
      Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = oRE.Execute(sInp)
      Dim sMsg
      If 1 <> oMTS.Count Then
         sMsg = oFmt.formatTwo("|{0}| didn't match /{1}/", sInp, oRE.Pattern)
      Else
         Dim sLoLa    : sLoLa    =      oMTS(0).SubMatches(0)
         Dim nDegrees : nDegrees = CDbl(oMTS(0).SubMatches(1))
         Dim nMinutes : nMinutes = CDbl(oMTS(0).SubMatches(2))
         Dim nSeconds : nSeconds = CDbl(oMTS(0).SubMatches(3))
         Dim nRes

'        Calculate the total number of seconds:
'        43'41" = (43*60 + 41) = 2621 seconds.
         nRes = nMinutes * 60 + nSeconds
'        WScript.Echo "***", nRes

'        The fractional part is total number of seconds divided by 3600:
'        2621 / 3600 = ~0.728056
         nRes = nRes / 3600
'        WScript.Echo "***", nRes

'        Add fractional degrees to whole degrees to produce the final result:
'        87 + 0.728056 = 87.728056
         nRes = nDegrees + nRes
'        WScript.Echo "***", nRes

'        Since it is a West longitude coordinate, negate the result.
'        The final result is -87.728056.
         Select Case sLoLa
           Case "W"
             nRes = -nRes
         End Select

         sMsg = oFmt.formatArray(_
              "{0,-12}: R: {1,12:N6} E: {2,12:N6} D: {3,12:N6}" _
            , Array(sInp, nRes, nExp, nRes - nExp) _
         )
      End If
      WScript.Echo sMsg
  Next
```

Output:

```
Step00 - conversion a la wikipedia
================================================================
W87°43'41"  : R:   -87,728056 E:   -87,728056 D:     0,000000
================================================================
xpl.vbs: Erfolgreich beendet. (0) [0.08594 secs]
```

Starting from an input sample, I derive (a first attempt at) the Regexp
pattern

```
                "   W   87  ° 43  ' 41  "" "
  '                 0    1     2     3
  oRE.Pattern = "^([W])(\d+)°(\d+)'(\d+)""$"
```

For your data, something like this

```
                "   7  d 44  ' 31.495   ""  W    "
                "  41  d  3  ' 40.313   ""  N    "
  '                 0     1        2        3
  oRE.Pattern = "^(\d+)d(\d+)'(\d+\.\d+)""([WN])$"
```

may be appropriate.

To get the parts captured by the RegExps group ()s, I access and convert
the match's submatches

```
 Dim sLoLa    : sLoLa    =      oMTS(0).SubMatches(0)
 Dim nDegrees : nDegrees = CDbl(oMTS(0).SubMatches(1))
 Dim nMinutes : nMinutes = CDbl(oMTS(0).SubMatches(2))
 Dim nSeconds : nSeconds = CDbl(oMTS(0).SubMatches(3))
```

Then it's just computing according to the algorithm/formulas stolen
from Wikipedia (see the code/comments).

**(2) Get the data from your files**

If the files are not to big, you can .ReadAll() them into memory and
apply the RegExp in multiline mode:

```
  Dim oFmt : Set oFmt = New cFormat

  Dim oRE  : Set oRE  = New RegExp
  oRE.Global    = True
  oRE.Multiline = True
  '                 0     1        2        3
  oRE.Pattern = "^(\d+)d(\d+)'(\d+\.\d+)""([WN])$"

  Dim sAll : sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\f00.txt").ReadAll()
  WScript.Echo sAll

  WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray( _
      "|{0,-5}|{1,-11}|{2,-11}|{3,-15}|" _
    , Array("LoLa", "Degrees", "Minutes", "Seconds") _
  )

  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = oRE.Execute(sAll)
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT In oMTS
      Dim sLoLa    : sLoLa    =      oMT.SubMatches(3)
      Dim nDegrees : nDegrees = CDbl(oMT.SubMatches(0))
      Dim nMinutes : nMinutes = CDbl(oMT.SubMatches(1))
      Dim nSeconds : nSeconds = CDbl(oMT.SubMatches(2))

      WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray( _
          "|{0,-5}|{1,11:N2}|{2,11:N2}|{3,15:N6}|" _
        , Array(sLoLa, nDegrees, nMinutes, nSeconds) _
      )
  Next
```

output:

```
======================================================
7d44'31.495"W
41d3'40.313"N


|LoLa |Degrees    |Minutes    |Seconds        |
|W    |       7,00|      44,00|      31,495000|
|N    |      41,00|       3,00|      40,313000|
======================================================
```

Get the cFormat class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614633/dateadd-in-special-format/10616669#10616669)

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but the last echo call, the one that involves oFmt.formatArray is not printing anything. Any idea on why this is happening. I know he is getting the right file because the other echos are working.

Comment: I changed the pattern to  "^(\d+)d(\d+)\'(\d+\.\d+)""([WN]) *$" and know it's printing, but instead of 31,495000 in the seconds i get 31.495,000000 any idea on how i can address this problem ?

Comment: Based on you regional settings the CDbl function sees the . in your data as thousand separator. Pass all real number data through Replace(<string>, ".", ",").

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it now ;)