# date format function to display date as "Jan 13 2014"

Tags: vbscript, datetime-format

Is there any function to display date in the format `mmm-dd-yyyy` in VBScript?
eg. today's date as `Jan 22 2014`?

I tried using function

```
FormatDateTime(Now(), 2)
```

I got it as `16 January 2014`.

Is there any function/format to get it as `Jan 16 2014`?

Comment: Extensive examples here - [Format current date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a .NET Stringbuilder - for **all** your formatting needs - you get the most bang for the buck:

```
Option Explicit

Class cFormat
  Private m_oSB
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
  End Sub ' Class_Initialize
  Public Function formatOne(sFmt, vElm)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat sFmt, vElm
    formatOne = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatOne
  Public Function formatArray(sFmt, aElms)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aElms)
    formatArray = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatArray
End Class ' cFormat

Dim oFmt : Set oFmt = New cFormat
WScript.Echo oFmt.FormatOne("Today: {0:MMM dd yyyy}", Date())
WScript.Echo oFmt.FormatOne("Today: {0:yyyy-MM-dd [MMMM]}", Date())
```

Output:

```
cscript 21279700.vbs
Today: Jan 22 2014
Today: 2014-01-22 [Januar]
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616669/603855) for background.

Answer (score 0):

`FormatDate` formats a date according to the format configured in the system's regional settings. If you want a custom date format using VBScript builtins, you'd do it like this:

```
WScript.Echo MonthName(Month(Now), True) & " " & Day(Now) & " " & Year(Now)
```

Comment: Oh, apparently in general, at least in ASP, you have to do `MonthName(Month(myDate))`.

Comment: You're right. Apparently I had typed the snippet in my answer from (failing) memory instead of actually looking up the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58f13257). Thanks for the heads up. It's fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

Below function will help which is returning in "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" format. 
You can customize the format according to your need.

```
Function timeStampForLogging(t)
    Dim Months

    Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", _ 
                   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec") 


    timeStampForLogging =  Right("0" & Day(t),2)& "-" & _
    Months(Month(t)-1)  & "-" & _
    Year(t) & " " & _  
    Right("0" & Hour(t),2) & ":" & _
    Right("0" & Minute(t),2) & ":" & _
    Right("0" & Second(t),2) 
End Function
```

Comment: `Months(Right("0" & Month(t),2))` - not seriously?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I am still working on a vbscript file and same solution as above. and updated the answer as got the wrong output but hopefully this one is fine now