# not able to format results in Dateadd

Tags: vbscript, dateadd

```
Function CurrMonthName(dateval)
 Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", 0, dateval) 
CurrMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp)) 
CurrMonthName = replace(CurrMonthName , "%M",CurrMonthName)
```

i am trying to format the month name so that it displays first 3 letters. On searching found %M can be used. I tried using it in above code and results are not coming as expected. It is still displaying full month

Answer (score 1):

In **VBScript**, the way to get an abreviated Monthname is [MonthName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58f13257%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

```
>> WScript.Echo MonthName(Month(Date()), True)
>>
Jul
>>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643663/603855) for a more flexible way to format dates (and other kind of data).

Answer (score 0):

Use the function "Left" to cut the first off: Left("February",3) gives you "Feb"

Comment: Use **std** function MonthName(dtWhatever, True) instead.