# Code improvements for counting the pages of PDF files

Tags: algorithm, pdf, vbscript, wsh

How can I get the value of the total pages of all `PDF` into the folder? I would also that the output is written into a `.txt` file.

So, I need to know how can I get the number of the pages of all `PDF` and a way to put in a column all the pages numbers and the `PDF` names.

I would an output like this:

```
PDF file name          Number of page
-------------------------------------
firstpdffile           30 pages
secondpdffile          25 pages
thirdpdffile           10 pages
fourthpdffile           5 pages
-------------------------------------
Total                  70 pages
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Function getPdfPgCnt(ByVal sPath) 'Returns page count of file on passed path
    Dim strTStr

    With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        .Open
        .Charset = "x-ansi"
        .LoadFromFile sPath
        strTStr = .ReadText(-1)
    End With

    With (New RegExp)
        .Pattern = "Type\s*/Page[^s]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        getPdfPgCnt = .Execute(strTStr).Count
    End With

    If getPdfPgCnt = 0 Then getPdfPgCnt = 1
End Function

'--------------------------------
Dim oFso, iFile
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'enumerating pdf files in vbs's base directory
For Each iFile In oFso.getFolder(oFso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)).Files
    If LCase(oFso.GetExtensionName(iFile)) = "pdf" Then WScript.Echo iFile & " has "& getPdfPgCnt(iFile)&" pages."
Next
Set oFso = Nothing
'--------------------------------
```

---

I use this `.bat` file to run the script

```
@echo off
color 0A

@set currentdir="%cd%"

title PDF page counter

del temp1.txt
del temp2.txt
del temp3.txt
del output.txt

cscript pdfpagecount.vbs > temp1.txt

BatchSubstitute.bat "%cd%" "" temp1.txt > temp2.txt & BatchSubstitute.bat "\" "" temp2.txt > temp3.txt & Type temp3.txt | findstr /I /V /C:"Microsoft" >>output.txt & del temp1.txt & del temp2.txt & del temp3.txt

exit
```

---

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel I have added some details, do you need others?

Comment: Knowing next to nothing about cscript, I doubt that your script can handle compressed object streams (i.e. PDF 1.5++). Use a PDF library for parsing your PDFs: It will easily tell you the number of pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to concentrate on

1. table (header, body, footer) like output for console scripts
2. summing up values

What you need

1. .NET sprintf like formatting (class cFormat)
2. sum variable initialized to 0 before the loop, adding in the loop, output/use after the loop

In code:

```
' 14490628.vbs
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490628/code-improvements-for-counting-the-pages-of-pdf-files

Option Explicit

Dim oFS     : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sDir    : sDir     = "..\..\10041057\data"
Dim oFmt    : Set oFmt = New cFormat
Dim nFWidth : nFWidth  = 25                ' for file name
Dim nPWidth : nPWidth  = 15                ' for number of pages
Dim nLWidth : nLWidth  = nFWidth + nPWidth ' for whole line

Dim sRuler1 : sRuler1 = String(nLWidth, "=")
Dim sRuler2 : sRuler2 = String(nLWidth, "-")
Dim sFmtT   : sFmtT   = insertWidth("{4}{2}{0,-@F}{1,@P}{2}{3}", nFWidth, nPWidth)
Dim aDataT  : aDataT  = Array("PDF file name", "Number of pages", vbCrLf, sRuler2, sRuler1)
Dim sFmtF   : sFmtF   = insertWidth("{0,-@F}{1,@P}", nFWidth, nPWidth)
Dim aDataF  : aDataF  = Array("", 0)
Dim sFmtS   : sFmtS   = insertWidth("{3}{2}{0,-@F}{1,@P}{2}{4}", nFWidth, nPWidth)
Dim aDataS  : aDataS  = Array("Total", 0, vbCrLf, sRuler2, sRuler1)

WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray(sFmtT, aDataT)
Dim oFile
For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sDir).Files
    aDataF(0) = oFile.Name
    aDataF(1) = getPdfPgCnt(oFile.Path)
    WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray(sFmtF, aDataF)
    aDataS(1) = aDataS(1) + aDataF(1)
Next
WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray(sFmtS, aDataS)

Function getPdfPgCnt(sFSpec)
  ' stolen from the VBScript Docs
  Dim lowerbound : lowerbound = 1
  Dim upperbound : upperbound = 1000
  getPdfPgCnt = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
End Function

Function insertWidth(sFmt, nFWidth, nPWidth)
  insertWidth = Replace(Replace(sFmt, "@F", nFWidth), "@P", nPWidth)
End Function

' stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11262441/603855
Class cFormat
  Private m_oSB
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
  End Sub ' Class_Initialize
  Public Function formatOne(sFmt, vElm)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat sFmt, vElm
    formatOne = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatOne
  Public Function formatArray(sFmt, aElms)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aElms)
    formatArray = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatArray
End Class ' cFormat
```

output:

```
========================================
PDF file name            Number of pages
----------------------------------------
xpl.txt                              706
1.abc                                534
xpl.vbs                              580
1.txt                                290
xx.txt                               302
----------------------------------------
Total                               2412
========================================
```

Comment: I tried this and this doesn't return the correct page counts for PDF files. anyone else has this issue?

Comment: @slayernoah - everyone who does not read the code of my (fake) `getPdfPgCnt` function will have this issue. The OT's function may work, but I didn't test it.