# Creating folder with the system date in its name

Tags: vbscript, automation

I'm having a little issue creating a folder with a name that uses the current system date.
I found a Date function but I can't use it (I keep getting "Path not found" error). follows my code:

```
directory = "C:\Users\f8057612\Desktop\Bancos\Script_Operadoras\TEST\TESTFOLDER" & " - Day " & Date() & "\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    

If Not FSO.FolderExists(directory) Then
    FSO.CreateFolder directory 
End If
```

How could I use the "Date" function?
Any other way of creating a folder with the system date on it is also welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Please specify *exactly*: (1) How should the date part look like (2) Why can't you use Date()

Comment: (1) Year(4 digits)/Month(2digits)/Day(2digits). (2) When I use that "Date()" there i get an error. I can test now to see what error it was, but I suppose We cant just say "Date()"

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for string concatenation is

```
sA & sB
```

Compare that to your:

```
directory = "C:\Users\...\TESTFOLDER" & " - Day " Date() & "\"
```

To deal with the format part of your problem, see if you can't get an idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262441/603855).

Comment: I tried with the "&" that was missing... I still have an error in the "FSO.CreateFolder directory " line. It's a "Path not Found"

Comment: @CharlieVelez You get a `path not found` error, because your date format looks like this: `yyyy/mm/dd`. `FileSystemObject` methods consider both ``\`` and `/` as path separators, so you're trying to create a subfolder `dd` in a subfolder `mm` in a folder `...yyyy`, but `CreateFolder` can't create folders recursively. Replace `/` with a save character (e.g. `-`): `directory = "C:\Users\... - Day " & Replace(Date, "/", "-")`.

Answer (score -1):

`Date()` most likely returned some characters that can not be used as a folder name. Try wrap the `Date()` with function **Format**.

`Format(Date(), "yyyy.mm.dd")`

Comment: I'm trying making a variable receive this function as you told and placing it in the program, but i am having a "type mismatch: [:Format". Maybe it's function name is wrong? I'll take a look in MSDN...

Comment: VBScript doesn't have a built-in function `Format()`.

Comment: Sorry, it may only work within vba. Doing this on my BlackBerry, try `Replace(CStr(Date()),"/",".")`