# How to use Format() procedure in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, string-formatting

I would need some help with the Format function. I would to like this function in order to use scientific notation for my calculations. I understood that you should use Format(number,"e") to achieve this but I am constantly getting a runtime error saying that there was a type mismatch. 
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Format() exists in VBA & VB6 but not VBScript

Answer (score 2):

Use a .NET StringBuilder:

```
>> Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
>> sb.AppendFormat "{0:E}", 1234.5678
>> WScript.Echo sb.ToString()
>>
1,234568E+003
>>
```

[Background/Class/Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262441/603855)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion with the .Net StringBuilder! One more question: Can I use these commands line in a .vbs script?