# how to convert a number into mm:ss format using VBScript

Tags: time, vbscript

I want to convert a number (less than 3600) in mm:ss format using VBScript. The main issue that i am facing is to add leading zeroes in case i get a single digit.
For example:-
while trying to convert 306 in mm:ss format i get the output as 5:6 instead of 05:06.
This is my code..

```
entered_time = "306"
quotient = entered_time/60
quotient = Int(quotient)
MsgBox quotient
remainder = entered_time Mod 60
MsgBox remainder
time_format = quotient&":"&remainder
msgbox time_format
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this ;)

```
intTotalSecs = 306
MsgBox intTotalSecs & "(s) ===> " & ConvertTime(intTotalSecs),vbinformation,"output time format as hh:mm:ss"
'************************************************************
Function ConvertTime(intTotalSecs)
Dim intHours,intMinutes,intSeconds,Time
intHours = intTotalSecs \ 3600
intMinutes = (intTotalSecs Mod 3600) \ 60
intSeconds = intTotalSecs Mod 60
ConvertTime = LPad(intHours) & " h : " & LPad(intMinutes) & " m : " & LPad(intSeconds) & " s"
End Function
'************************************************************
Function LPad(v) 
 LPad = Right("0" & v, 2) 
End Function
'************************************************************
```

Comment: **Either** LPad() or `intHours = "0"&intHours`.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple `if remainder < 10` ?

Comment: yes that would work but isn't there a function in vbscript that will help?

Comment: there's surely a string formatting library, but I think looking that one up is as trivial as my solution, especially in your case

Answer (score 0):

If your locale/regional settings are suitable, you just do:

```
>> setlocale "de-de"
>> secs = 308
>> ts = TimeSerial(0, 0, secs)
>> WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(ts, vbLongTime)
>>
00:05:08
```

If that's not possible, put some effort in a .NET based format class like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262441/603855).